# Template iterator with QString

Tags: c++, qt, templates, iterator, qstring

I had a problem with passing a template iterator of `vector<'T>` to a function `QString::fromStdString(const std::string&)`.

I had my function that in case of type `T` can convert a `std::string` to `QString` or `int` to `QString` and than add in into my `QTableWidget` cell.

The issue happen with converting from `std::string` with:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘QString::fromStdString(int&)’ QString text = QString::fromStdString(*it);
```

I can't understand why type of iterator object has `int&`.  What I do wrong? Can I convert it in other way?

```
template<typename T>
void Dialog::Browse(vector<T> *list, int &counter, QTableWidget *table,     int column)
{
    QTableWidgetItem* item = 0;
    typename vector<T>::iterator it;
    for (it = list->begin(); it != list->end(); ++it){
        QString text;
        if (typeid(*list) == typeid(vector<string>)){
            //QString text = QString::fromUtf8(static_cast<string>(it)->c_str());
            QString text = QString::fromStdString(*it);
        } else if (typeid(*list) == typeid(vector<int>)){
            QString text = QString::number(*it);
        }

        item = new QTableWidgetItem(text);
        item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
        table->setItem(counter, column, item);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that if statements don't stop the code from being compiled.  When you do

```
if (typeid(*list) == typeid(vector<string>)){
    //QString text = QString::fromUtf8(static_cast<string>(it)->c_str());
    QString text = QString::fromStdString(*it);
} else if (typeid(*list) == typeid(vector<int>)){
    QString text = QString::number(*it);
}
```

The line `QString text = QString::fromStdString(*it);` will be compiled no matter if `list` is a `vector<string>` or not.  Since when you called it with a `vector<int>` it tries to compile that code using a `int&` and you get your error.

If you have C++17 you can use a [if constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) like

```
if constexpr (typeid(*list) == typeid(vector<string>)){
    //QString text = QString::fromUtf8(static_cast<string>(it)->c_str());
    QString text = QString::fromStdString(*it);
} else if constexpr (typeid(*list) == typeid(vector<int>)){
    QString text = QString::number(*it);
}
```

And now the code will only compile if the condition is true.

If you do not have access to C++17 you will need to split the function into overloads/specializations to keep the type dependent code separated.